# Javascript expression `["Java", "Python","Javascript"][Symbol.iterator]().next().value` evaluates to first value of a given array

Tags: javascript, arrays, iterator, symbols

I have been asked in interview to get the first value of an array without using index and any helper function.
Then interviewer give me the below solution which works but not able to exactly figure out how?

```js
const firstValue = ["Java", "Python","Javascript"][Symbol.iterator]().next().value;

console.log('First Value: ', firstValue);
```

If anyone can give more insight on would be helpful and appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: In addition to the answers below. See also the Iterator Pattern on Wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern#JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the rundown:

- Arrays are *iterable*, which means they have a method available via the property named with the Symbol `Symbol.iterator` which behaves as the spec says it should.
- When you call that method, it returns an iterator.
- Iterators have a `next` method you use to get the "next" result from the iterator: The first call returns the first result, the second call returns the second result, etc.
- The results are objects with a boolean `done` property and a `value` property with the actual value for that iteration. *(Technically, both are optional: `done` defaults to `false` and `value` defaults to `undefined`. But iterators provided by native JavaScript objects have both properties explicitly.)*

So here's how that statement does the above:

```
//                                +----------------------------------------------- create the array
//                                |                       +----------------------- get its `Symbol.iterator` method
//                                |                       |         +------------- call it
//                                |                       |         |   +--------- call the `next` method of the iterator to get the first result object
//                                |                       |         |   |      +-- get its `value` property
//                                |                       |         |   |      |
//                                |                       |         |   |      |
//                                |                       |         |   |      |
//                                |                       |         |   |      |
//                                |                       |         |   |      |
//                                |                       |         |   |      |
//                 \vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv/\vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv/\/ \vvvv/ \vvv/
const firstValue = ["Java", "Python","Javascript"][Symbol.iterator]().next().value;
```

Or perhaps more clearly:

```js
// Create the array
const array = ["Java", "Python","Javascript"];
// Get its `Symbol.iterator` method
const iteratorMethod = array[Symbol.iterator];
// Call it
const iterator = iteratorMethod.call(array);
// Call the `next` method of the iterator to get the first result object
const resultObject = iterator.next();
// Get its `value` property
const firstValue = resultObject.value;

console.log(firstValue); // "Java"
```

Comment: How does you get to know arrays are iterable. What else is iterable and how does we get know whether its iterable or not?

Comment: @ricky - I've studied the additions to JavaScript in ES2015+ in depth (in fact, I have [a book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1119367956) coming out on them :-) ). But in general you learn these things from [the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/) and/or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/javascript). Arrays, strings, Maps, Sets, and generators (the things generator functions create) are all iterable (so are DOM `NodeList`s per the DOM spec, which is implemented in modern browsers) (`HTMLCollection` isn't specified as iterable, but some browsers make it iterable).

Comment: Thats great thanks for explanation. 
I guess the solution is more about iterator So I will dig deep into it. 
Waiting for your book as well :)

Comment: @ricky - :-) Iterators are covered in depth in Chapter 6.

Answer (score 2):

The `[Symbol.iterator]` is a special property that make any object in JavaScript an ***Iterable***. So in an Array which is an *Iterable* object this property is present.

The role of this property is to return an ***Iterator*** object having the `next()` method. Using the Iterator returned you can iterate through the Array or your data in the Iterable Object.

You can also create a custom Iterable object, from which you can get an Iterator by invoking its [[Sysmbol.iterator]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) method. This syntax []is new with ES6 where you can use any `Symbol` as the name for a method inside an class, this is known as computed property.

In the below snippet you can see how to use `[Symbol.iterator]` as a method name to make my own iterable object. This is a very simple example demonstrating the usage of `[Symbol.iterator]` there are other ways of doing the same:

```js
class CustomIterable{

   constructor(start, stop){
      this.start = start;
      this.stop = stop;
   }
   //This property makes this an Iterable
   [Symbol.iterator](){
    return this;
   }
   //This makes this an Iterator also
   next(){
    return this.start !== this.stop ? {value: this.start++, done: false} 
                                    : {value: this.stop, done: true};
   }
 
}

const cutomIterable = new CustomIterable(0, 11);
console.log(cutomIterable[Symbol.iterator]().next().value);
//This object can be a target of the for..of loop
for( let val of cutomIterable){
  console.log(val);
}
```